# store wise email not working magento 1.5

Tags: magento

I have 5 different store in my website. My default store is English, 
   1) when someone registered from english store he get currect email in English language
   2) when someone registered from german store he also get email in English language instead of german language.

Any idea for solving this issues.

Thanks,
Hardik

Comment: Have you upload language pack for each store?

Comment: Yes i have uploaded language pack all the store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Finally i got the solution for new customer registration emails.
Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php

in this file i have make some changes as following.
find this line of code
if (!$storeId) 
{
    $storeId = $this->_getWebsiteStoreId($this->getSendemailStoreId());
}

and replace with

$storeId = ($storeId == '0')?$this->getSendemailStoreId():$storeId;
if ($this->getWebsiteId() != '0' && $storeId == '0') 
{
    $storeIds = Mage::app()->getWebsite($this->getWebsiteId())->getStoreIds();
    reset($storeIds);
    $storeId = current($storeIds);
}
```

Thanks,